# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null, how can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, algorithm

I'm still studying javascript and to practice I'm doing a series of exercises from codewars.com, and I'm having trouble with one of them.
The request is as follows:
Given an array of integers.

Return an array, where the first element is the count of positives numbers and the second element is sum of negative numbers.

If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array.

For input [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15], you should return [10, -65].

I made the following algorithm which works in all cases:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  var arrOutput = []; //declare the final array
  var pos = 0; //declare the positive 
  var neg = 0; //declare the negative
  var check, ss;

  for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x++){
    if(input[x]>0){ pos++; }
    else{ neg = neg + input[x] ; }
    arrOutput = [pos, neg]
  }
  
  return arrOutput;
}
```

but it returns me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at countPositivesSumNegatives (test.js:8:29)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:39:18)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

and because of this error i can't pass the test.
How can i solve it, and why it gives me this error?

Comment: `If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array.` You're not always being passed an array, you're also being passed `null` sometimes. if `input` is null then `input.length` doesn't work. You'll need to check for the `null` somewhere in your code.

Comment: The previous commenters got it right. Just add a check for null: if (input === null) ...
You also want to move the arrOutput = [pos, neg] outside the loop, otherwise each iteration is just overwriting the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we call your function with the input equal to null / undefined:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) { // input = null
  var arrOutput = []; // OK
  var pos = 0; //OK 
  var neg = 0; //OK
  var check, ss; // OK

  for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x++){ // error is here
  ...
```

In JS, null is defined as: "a primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value"

So when you try to access a member of null, JS is going to throw an error because null has no members.

You have a variable for check, but you should write code for that check to see if the input is equal to any of the illegal values you mentioned.

A simple, brute force, solution would be to just check if the input is equal to any illegal values. E.g.

`if (input === null || input === undefined || input === []) return []`

Before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "input?.length" within your "for" loop.

There is no "length" property to "input" so you get an error.

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  var arrOutput = []; 
  var pos = 0;  
  var neg = 0; 
  var check, ss;
    
  for (var x = 0; x < input?.length; x++){
    if(input[x]>0){ pos++; }
    else{ neg = neg + input[x] ; }
    arrOutput = [pos, neg]
  }
      
  return arrOutput;
}
```

Comment: This is more like a comment.